# Flutter Web | Rendering more than one flutter instance in the same webpage

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, web

I am creating a flutter web project which will be used in another website created with amber or reactjs. There will be some data transaction back and forth.

My approach was creating a flutter project and building my uis and then running *Flutter build web* in that project and copying the main.dart.js from that project and adding it to a new flutter project as main2.dart.js

````html
<body>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #15202b;
        color: #ffffff;
        margin: 0;
      }

      div {
        font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-top: 48px;
        height: 500px;
        width: 800px;
        float: left;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="element1" height="300px"></div>
    <div id="element2" height="300px"></div>
    <div id="element3" height="300px"></div>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", async function (ev) {
        var element1 = document.querySelector("#element1");
        var element2 = document.querySelector("#element2");
        var element3 = document.querySelector("#element3");
        await loadFlutterEntryPoint(element1, "main2.dart.js");
        await loadFlutterEntryPoint(element2, "main2.dart.js");
        await loadFlutterEntryPoint(element3, "main2.dart.js");
      });

      const loadFlutterEntryPoint = async (element, entrypointUrl) => {
        await _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          serviceWorker: {
            serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          },
          entrypointUrl: entrypointUrl,
          onEntrypointLoaded: async function (engineInitializer) {
            let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine({
              hostElement: element,
            });
            await appRunner.runApp();
          },
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>```

I was expecting to see both of the flutter UIs rendering on different divs but its not. Its only rendering the first one.
````